# Custom Context Menu in v-list vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a couple of questions regarding implementing a custom Context Menu on the right click of a list item.

**1st Question:** I have this component that has

```
<v-list>
  <menu-items
    v-for="record in Records"
    :key="record.id"  
  >
  <template v-slot:someslotA>
  <template v-slot:someslotB>
 </menu-items
</v-list>
```

And inside this menu-items script, I have Vuetify's `v-list-item`

```
<v-list-item >
  <!-- icon -->
   <v-list-item-icon>
     <slot name="someslotA">
       
    </slot>
  </v-list-item-icon>
</v-list-item >
```

Now I want to implement a custom Context Menu whenever any of the list items is right-clicked.
How do I achieve that?

**2nd Question:** Let's say I encapsulate this code more and add another component on top of the menu-item component. For example

```
 <my-list
   :records="items"
 ></my-list>
```

And now my list contains the menu-item component code. eg my-list context

```
<v-list>
 <menu-items
    v-for="record in Records"
    :key="record.id"  
  >
  <template v-slot:someslotA>
  <template v-slot:someslotB>
 </menu-items
</v-list>
```

So can I now implement Custom Context Menu on the parent component (my-list) or can it only come with

```
<menu-items
        v-for="record in Records"
        :key="record.id"  
      >
```

Comment: Can this help you- https://codepen.io/SimpleSoftwareIO/pen/yNwYJb